# Are vim.cmd() and vim.api.nvim_command() the same, if not, what are the differences?

Tags: neovim, lua

I'm a little confused. Is `vim.cmd` just a shorthand for `vim.api.nvim_command` or are they used for different things?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`vim.cmd(command)` calls either of these two lua APIs:

- `vim.api.nvim_cmd`: when `command` is a table
- `vim.api.nvim_exec`: when `command` is a string

[The lua code for `vim.cmd`](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/afb7efb3733962649f3c0897a25dc5fff60a66c6/runtime/lua/vim/_editor.lua#L335-L368):

```lua
vim.cmd = setmetatable({}, {
  __call = function(_, command)
    if type(command) == 'table' then
      return vim.api.nvim_cmd(command, {})
    else
      return vim.api.nvim_exec(command, false)
    end
  end,
  -- CODE TRUNCATED
  -- not necessary for this SO answer
  -- visit full source code on github
  -- https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/afb7efb3733962649f3c0897a25dc5fff60a66c6/runtime/lua/vim/_editor.lua#L335-L368
})
```

---

Both of these APIs differ slightly from `vim.api.nvim_command`. When to use which is laid out in `:h nvim_command`:

```
nvim_command({command})                                       *nvim_command()*
    Executes an Ex command.

    On execution error: fails with VimL error, updates v:errmsg.

    Prefer using |nvim_cmd()| or |nvim_exec()| over this. To evaluate multiple
    lines of Vim script or an Ex command directly, use |nvim_exec()|. To
    construct an Ex command using a structured format and then execute it, use
    |nvim_cmd()|. To modify an Ex command before evaluating it, use
    |nvim_parse_cmd()| in conjunction with |nvim_cmd()|.
```

Comment: Glad you are also addressing `vim.api.nvim_command`, since it has nothing to do with `vim.cmd`. Given the `vim.api.nvim_command` help: When should I even use `nvim_command` over `cmd` (`vim.api.nvim_cmd`, `vim.api.nvim_exec`)?

Comment: @MartinBraun, probably never. It's a simple api function that only calls the C function for ex commands. It's an old api (from api level 1); and I'm guessing it's functionally deprecated/superseded by the other two more robust apis (`nvim_exec` from lvl 7 and `nvim_cmd` from lvl 10).

Comment: @MartinBraun here are source codes for the three APIs: 1) [`nvim_command`](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/afb7efb3733962649f3c0897a25dc5fff60a66c6/src/nvim/api/vimscript.c#L113-L119), 2) [`nvim_cmd`](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/afb7efb3733962649f3c0897a25dc5fff60a66c6/src/nvim/api/command.c#L305-L722), and 3) [`nvim_exec`](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/afb7efb3733962649f3c0897a25dc5fff60a66c6/src/nvim/api/vimscript.c#L47-L100). Notice that the latter two apis are significantly more intricate. Also notice their `FUNC_API_SINCE` value, which signifies how old they are.

Answer (score 1):

`vim.cmd(·)` is the same as `vim.api.nvim_exec(·, false)` when passed a string.  However, when passed a table, it behaves like `vim.api.nvim_cmd(·, {})`

```
vim.cmd { cmd = 'write', args = { "myfile.txt" }, bang = true }
```